# deploying hybris cuppy project on pivotal cloud foundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, sap-commerce-cloud

How can i deploy hybris sample cuppy  project on pivotal cloud foundry,i am able to run it locally and wanted to deploy the cuppy project on PCF.When i am trying to push the cuppy through STS cloud foundry plugin,i am facing this issue.

Error: Could not find or load main class de.hybris.platform.cuppy.data.BetGenerator

Instance (index 0) failed to start accepting connections

App instance exited with guid 3051204e-5b2a-4a21-ad47-f948b3c822f6 payload: {"cc_partition"=>"default", "droplet"=>"3051204e-5b2a-4a21-ad47-f948b3c822f6", "version"=>"85812d42-c45b-4358-895a-1baea34a737e", "instance"=>"3c85bf944f1d48cba54fe9ff314dc737", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_status"=>1, "exit_description"=>"failed to accept connections within health check timeout", "crash_timestamp"=>1429885131}

Answer (score 0):

Are you binding your app to start on port given to you by Cloud Foundry?  You can get the hostname from an environment variable called `VCAP_APP_PORT`.

Comment: Hi Jeff,Thanks for the reply.You meant to say add this ENV variable in the cloud foundry Environment variables?.If so can you please let me know how to add that.

Comment: No, you can read that ENV variable from Cloud Foundry and it will give you a port to start your app on.